# How to check if a document exisits in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I am trying to check if a document exists in MongoDB and then based on that either update the document or create a new one. However only the if statement is being recorded. I have checked that the value of documentExists is null if no document is in mongo.

```
router.post("/mongo", async function (req, res) {

const documentExists = await Files.findOne({
    _id: req.body.id,
  });

 if (documentExists) {
    try {
      Files.updateOne(
        { _id: documentExist._id },
        { flag: req.body.flag },
        function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          } else {
            res.send(result);
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    }
  } else { 
    CREATE NEW DOCUMENT
   }


})
```

Comment: You can try using [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#insert-a-new-document-if-no-match-exists-upsert) instead of _find_ and _insert/update_.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)   to update if there is any existing document in the collection, if there is no matching document the query returns null.